# Opencvのグレースケール変換時にエラーが起きてしまう。

Tags: python, windows, api, opencv, azure

opencvとFaceAPIを使ってカメラから画像を取得し感情推定するプログラムを作ろうと思っているのですが、下記コードを実行すると画像が読み込めないというエラーが出てしまいます。

[python opencvでグレースケール変換を行いたい - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/134267)

このサイトを参考にしてみたのですが実行結果は変わりませんでした...
何が原因なのかもわからず検索もできないため、詰まっています。なにか解決方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

実行プログラム

````
import requests
import json
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

##初期設定
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) #0にするとmacbookのカメラ、1にすると外付けのUSBカメラにできる
csv_name = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M')#csvファイルとして保存するファイル名
data_name = ["anger","contempt","disgust","fear","happiness",'sadness','surprise']#保存データの系列
emotion_data =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]#初期値
count = 0#撮影回数を示すカウンタ

##顔認識の設定
cascade_path =  r'C:/Users/shota/opencvcascade/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'# 顔判定で使うxmlファイルを指定する。(opencvのpathを指定)
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)

##Faceの設定
subscription_key = '#########################'#ここに取得したキー１を入力
assert subscription_key
face_api_url = '#################################3/face/v1.0/detect'#ここに取得したエンドポイントのURLを入力

##実行
while True:
    r, img = cap.read()
    #cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\shota\opencvcascade\img " + str(now) + '.jpg')
    assert img is not None, 'cannot open file as img.'
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#グレースケールに変換
    faces=cascade.detectMultiScale(img_gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(100, 100))#顔判定 minSizeで顔判定する際の最小の四角の大きさを指定できる。(小さい値を指定し過ぎると顔っぽい小さなシミのような部分も判定されてしまう。)

    if len(faces) > 0: #顔を検出した場合
        for face in faces:
            now = 1#撮影時間
            filename = r"C:\Users\shota\opencvcascade\img "+str(now)+'.jpg'#保存するfilename
            cv2.imwrite(filename, img)#画像の書き出し
            now += 1
            image_data = open(filename, "rb").read()#処理をする画像を選択
            headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
                       'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
            params = {
                'returnFaceId': 'true',
                'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
                'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
                }
            response = requests.post(face_api_url, headers=headers,
                                        params=params, data=image_data)#FaceAPIで解析

            response.raise_for_status()
            analysis = response.json()#json出力

            #faceのjsonから抽出する項目をピック
            result = [analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['anger'],analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['contempt'],
                        analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['disgust'],analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['fear'],
                        analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['happiness'],analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['sadness'],
                        analysis[0]['faceAttributes']['emotion']['surprise']]

            emotion_data = np.array(result) + np.array(emotion_data)

            df = pd.DataFrame({now:emotion_data},
                            index=data_name)#取得データをDataFrame1に変換しdfとして定義

            if count == 0:#初期
                print(df)
            else:
                df = pd.concat([df_past,df],axis = 1, sort = False)#dfを更新
                print(df)

            plt.plot(df.T)#dfの行列を反転
            plt.legend(data_name)#凡例を表示
            plt.draw()#グラフ描画
            plt.pause(4)#ウェイト時間（=Azure更新時間）
            plt.cla()#グラフを閉じる

            count = count + 1#撮影回数の更新
            df_past = df#df_pastを更新

            df.T.to_csv(csv_name+'.csv')#感情分析結果をcsvファイルとして書き出し ```
````

エラー画面

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1e1e4e967c4d> in <module>
     28     r, img = cap.read()
     29     #cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\shota\opencvcascade\img " + str(now) + '.jpg')
---> 30     assert img is not None, 'cannot open file as img.'
     31     img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#グレースケールに変換
     32     #faces=cascade.detectMultiScale(img_gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(100, 100))#顔判定 minSizeで顔判定する際の最小の四角の大きさを指定できる。(小さい値を指定し過ぎると顔っぽい小さなシミのような部分も判定されてしまう。)

AssertionError: cannot open file as img.
```

引用元
[AzureのFaceを使ってリアルタイム感情分析をしてみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/daiarg/items/0fa6759e450c18c502b3)
[Azure Face API で写真から感情判定 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/doyodoyo/items/bb0f20a1076fce9a8de6)

pyplotが必要ないと思ったので二個目のサイトの”まずはmacで試してみる”というコードと一個目のサイトのコードをくっつけてプログラムを完成させたいと思い試行錯誤していました。

開発環境
windows10
anaconda

Comment: タイトルの「グレースケール変換時」にまで辿り着いていないのでは？ カメラからの読み込みでデータが無くて`assert`が失敗しているように見えます。こちらの記事 [OpenCV 接続したカメラから動画を取得しよう (Python)](https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/python/opencv-videocapture-camera.html) のプログラムで画像読み込みを確認してみてはどうでしょう？ それから類似ポスト先 [opencvでグレースケール変換時にcvtcolorエラーが出てしまう](https://teratail.com/questions/294707)

Comment: リンク先コードを試してみると正常に動きました。##初期設定の場所がいけないのかwhile文の中がどっちが問題なのかがわかれば少しでも近づくんですけどね...

Comment: そうすると、問題が発生するのが最初の`read`か、2回目以後の`read`か、といったように発生タイミングを切り分けて、どの辺の処理が影響してそうかを絞り込んでみてください。

Comment: 具体的にどうやって絞り込めばのでしょうか。初心者でどこをコメントアウトすれば片方だけ動くのかがわかりません。あと関係ないかもしれないのですがfilenameでjpgで保存しているのに読み込むときににバイナリファイルモードになっているのは何か関係ありますでしょうか。

Comment: `read`の前後や、他に気になる処理の近辺に`print`文を入れて、かつ何かのカウンタ値を定義してどの場所を何回通ったかをコンソールに出力するようにして、どこまで動作しているかを確認するといった手法があります。

Comment: こんな記事 [(第4回)Python + OpenCV で遊んでみる(リアルタイム顔検知編)](https://itport.cloud/?p=6983) でローカルな処理は出来ていそうなので、後はAzureのAPI関連でしょうか。

Comment: Azureは自分はキーとエンドポイントしかいじってないので余計にわからなくなります...

Comment: まあ単にカメラから画像が入手できない条件なりタイミングなりが存在するのかもしれませんし、以前のコメントに書いたように、何処まで/何回実行したかを多数の箇所に`print`の挿入で実行して確かめてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 「assert img is not None, 'cannot open file as img.'」というassertは正しいのですか？
その前に　r, img = cap.read(); でキャプチャーした画像をimg

Comment: 時間切れで途中になったので、追記します。
キャプチャーした画像をimgに入れているので、アサートを挙げるとしたらimgに画像が入らなかった場合ではないでしょうか。
そうであれば、「assert img is None, 'cannot open file as img.'」となりませんか？

Comment: 具体的にどの文の後にassert img is not None, 'cannot open file as img.'を入れるということでしょうか？

Comment: それか、前コメントの「(第4回)Python + OpenCV で遊んでみる(リアルタイム顔検知編)」とかこちらの [OpencvとPythonで監視カメラ(SecurityCamera)を作る方法](https://qiita.com/igor-bond16/items/5f213f7b8430e0e9435f)のように、`assert`で例外にするのではなく、`cap.read()`の結果がエラーや無効だったら、そこで処理の終了とかその回の処理はスキップして行わないとかの対処を考えた方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: カメラのエラーではなくhaarcascade_frontalface_alt.xmlなどを同一のフォルダに移動させたところこのエラーは解決しました。ありがとうございました。